# Not sure if ajax method saved rails form to the database,how do i doublecheck?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two questions.First, i have tried to submit a rails form with jquery (ajax method),but i am not sure if it really saved the data,so can anybody double check my code if it is correct?Secondly according to my controller how could i display the data i just saved?I am using Rails 3.1,Sqlite 3.Thank you in advance.
Here is  my code

FORM

```
 <%=form_for :user do |f|%>
 <%= f.label :school %>
 <%= f.text_field :school,:size=>"45",:class=>"round",:id=>"school" %>
 <%= f.submit "save and continue",{:class=>"savebutton" }%>
 <%end%>
```

JQUERY(application.js)

```
  $(".savebutton").click(function() {  
$('form').submit(function() { 
    var formToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'), 
    data: formToSubmit,
    dataType: "JSON" 
      });
 return false; 
});
 });
```

CONTROLLER

```
   class SchoolController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :json

  def create
  @school = current_user.schools.build(params[:school].merge(:user => current_user))

 @school = current_user.school.build(params[:school].merge(:user => current_user))

   if @school.save
  respond_with @school
 else
  respond_with @school.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity
 end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rails console` or `rails console --sandbox` for this. Sandbox means you can play with your database in console and it will stay unchanged. Just open the console and type

```
School.last
```

after you submitted the form. You should see a hash of values you've just entered in form.

I've found a solution to your problem after looking into server log. You are using GET method instead of POST for your ajax request. Also, you don't have `$(document).ready(function() {});` anywhere so your javascript code will never be triggered.

Change your application.js code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".savebutton").click(function() {  
  $('form').submit(function() { 
     var formToSubmit = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr('action'), 
      data: formToSubmit,
      dataType: "JSON" 
    });
    return false; 
   });
  });
});
```

Remember, server log is your friend in debugging ajax, this time it was telling you that you're using a wrong method (GET).

Comment: Now i know for sure that it didnt save the data,what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

while I haven't read your code in depth, to answer the question of whether to double check things got saved you can either read the console output or open up the database console

Opening database console:

On commandline type

```
rails dbconsole
```

You should be booted into sqlite. From here some useful commands are:

```
.schema

select * from tablename;
```

Hope this helps!